# Using @JoinColumn in EmbeddedId generates org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a composite id, one of the fields of which is a foreign key to another tables.

[image]

I have tried to implement this with the following classes -

**Tracking.java:**

```
public class Tracking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long trackingId;
    private String accountNumber;
    private TrackingType trackingType;
}
```

**TrackingUseCaseDetails.java**

```
public class UseCaseStatus implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7058248210575975131L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;
    private String status;
    private String resourceId;
}
```

**ID.java**

```
public class UseCaseStatusId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7037374226692973832L;

    @JoinColumn(name = "trackingId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Tracking tracking;
    private TrackingUseCase trackingUseCase;
}
```

I however am getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Tracking, at table: TrackingUseCaseDetails, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(tracking)]
```

Any suggestions on how to solve the error/improve the code?

Comment: Did you read the documentation about the JPA composite ID ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class UseCaseStatus implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UseCaseStatusId id;

    @MapsId("tracking")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "trackingId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Tracking tracking;

    private String resourceId;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class UseCaseStatusId implements Serializable {

    //@JoinColumn(name = "trackingId", updatable = false, nullable = false) <- prob not required
    private long tracking;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    //implement equals() and hashcode() : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Embedded_Id
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know what to search for within the documentation itself. That worked!